# How to add a line at the beginning of my file from normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode

I'm trying to add the line `HELLO WORLD` to the beginning of my file from normal mode.
How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean `ggOHELLO WORLD<Esc>`? Please [edit] the question to further explain what you'd like to do, what you have tried, why it didn't work, and so on... Thanks!

Comment: Also `:0put ='hello world'<cr>gUU`